m.if3 not providing consistent output?
I am trying to use the m.if3 in GEKKO such that the first count should always have a threshold of 40 and below but the if3 is not providing consistent output. In most cases it obeys the threshold but in some cases it does not. For example in the code below it gives a higher count than 40 which should not be the case. I am not sure why the if3 is not working here.
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()

# Constants
var_cost = 9
p_cost = 12
final = 100
duration = 50

x = m.Var(integer=True, lb=0)  
y = m.Var(integer=True, lb = 1, ub=duration)       

first_rate = 0.3
second_rate = 0.0
third_rate = 0.5

count1 = m.Intermediate(first_rate * y * x)
cost1 = m.Intermediate(first_rate * p_cost * y + var_cost) * x

stop = 2

count2 = m.Intermediate(second_rate * stop * x)
cost2 = m.Intermediate(second_rate * p_cost * stop + var_cost) * x

remaining = duration - y - stop # 50 - 2 - y 

count3 = m.Intermediate(third_rate * remaining * x)
cost3 = m.Intermediate(third_rate * p_cost * remaining + var_cost) * x

count = m.if3(count1 - 40, count1, count1 + count2 + count3)
cost = m.if3(count1 - 40,  cost1, cost1 + cost2 + cost3)

m.Minimize(cost)
m.Equation(count >= final)
m.options.SOLVER = 1 # for MINLP solution
m.solve(disp=False)
out = x.value[0]
print(f'out: {out}')
print("cost:", cost.value[0])
print("first count:", count1.value[0])
print("second count:", count2.value[0])
print("third count:", count3.value[0])
print("duration before stop:", y.value[0])

I tried the above code and I got the following output with APOPT:
out: 6.0
cost: 1371.6
first count: 64.8
second count: 0.0
third count: 36.0
duration before stop: 36.0


It appears that the solution is correct based on how the equations are formulated. Here are a few additional print statements to help with the analysis:
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()

# Constants
var_cost = 9
p_cost = 12
final = 100
duration = 50

x = m.Var(integer=True, lb=0)  
y = m.Var(integer=True, lb = 1, ub=duration)       

first_rate = 0.3
second_rate = 0.0
third_rate = 0.5

count1 = m.Intermediate(first_rate * y * x)
cost1 = m.Intermediate((first_rate * p_cost * y + var_cost) * x)

stop = 2

count2 = m.Intermediate(second_rate * stop * x)
cost2 = m.Intermediate((second_rate * p_cost * stop + var_cost) * x) 

remaining = duration - y - stop # 50 - 2 - y 

count3 = m.Intermediate(third_rate * remaining * x)
cost3 = m.Intermediate((third_rate * p_cost * remaining + var_cost) * x) 

count = m.if3(count1 - 40, count1, count1 + count2 + count3)
cost = m.if3(count1 - 40,  cost1, cost1 + cost2 + cost3)

m.Minimize(cost)
m.Equation(count >= final)
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=False) 

print(f"cost 1: {cost1.value[0]}")
print(f"cost 2: {cost2.value[0]}")
print(f"cost 3: {cost3.value[0]}")
print("cost:", cost.value[0])
print(f"count 1: {count1.value[0]}")
print(f"count 2: {count2.value[0]}")
print(f"count 3: {count3.value[0]}")
print(f"count: {count.value[0]}")
print(f'x: {x.value[0]}')
print(f"y: {y.value[0]}")

The solution is:
cost 1: 831.6
cost 2: 54.0
cost 3: 486.0
cost: 1371.6
count 1: 64.8
count 2: 0.0
count 3: 36.0
count: 100.8
x: 6.0
y: 36.0

Each equation is listed below with the solution values substituted:
count1 = 0.3 * 36 * 6 = 64.8
cost1 = (0.3 * 12 * 36 + 9) * 6 = 831.6

count2 = 0.0 * 2 * 6 = 0
cost2 = (0.0 * 12 * 2 + 9) * 6 = 54

remaining = 50 - 36 - 2 = 12 

count3 = 0.5 * 12 * 6 = 36
cost3 = (0.5 * 12 * 12 + 9) * 6 = 486

count = m.if3(24.8, 64.8, 100.8) = 100.8
cost = m.if3(24.8,  831.6, 1371.6) = 1371.6

m.Minimize(1371.6)
m.Equation(100.8 >= 100)

The m.if3 statement may be the source of confusion. Here is additional information from the Gekko documentation:
y = if3(condition,x1,x2)

IF conditional with a binary switch variable. The traditional method
for IF statements is not continuously differentiable and can cause a
gradient-based optimizer to fail to converge. The if3 method uses a
binary switching variable to determine whether y=x1 (when condition<0)
or y=x2 (when condition>=0):
Usage: y = m.if3(condition,x1,x2)
Inputs: condition: GEKKO variable, parameter, or expression
x1 and x2: GEKKO variable, parameter, or expression
Output: GEKKO variable
y = x1 when condition<0
y = x2 when condition>=0
When condition~0, the solution may be x1 or x2. Gekko computes a
numerical solution with a solver tolerance that is 1e-6 by default.

Setting a constraint:
m.Equation(count1<=40)

gives an infeasible solution as expected because we cannot simultaneously have count1<=40 and count>=100.

How is your result different from the OP's result?

My question exactly...it's not returning the first count as 40 or below 40. It's giving the same output as I had.

Okay, I'll dig into it a little more. The OP's result was likely obtained on a Linux or MacOS platform where IPOPT local doesn't exist so it defaults to APOPT. I updated the post to use remote=True so that everyone gets the same result, regardless of platform.

Right, but even when I remove the condition m.Equation(count >= final), it still does not obey the threshold of count1 <= 40. I do not understand why that is?

Also, why do we need to specify additional m.Equation(count1 <=40) when we have already specified a threshold at 40 in the m.if3?

The m.if3() doesn't specify a limit. If the condition count1-40 is less than zero then the result count is equal to count1. If count1-40 is greater than zero then count is equal to count1 + count2 + count3. Does that help?
